# How do I bind a WPF control's content to its container's DataContext so I can apply a DataTemplateSelector based on that object?

Tags: wpf, datatemplateselector

I'm trying to bind a WPF window atop a ViewModel that contains two collections, A and B. I'm attempting to use DataTemplates to display either A or B depending on the setting of a flag in my ViewModel.

To that end, I've set the window's `DataContext = ViewModel`. However, when I attempt to bind a `ContentControl` to that DataContext and apply a `DataTemplateSelector` to it, the `item` parameter of the selector's `SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)` method is always null:

```
<Window [snip] Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- DataTemplate and Selector declarations -->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"              
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
    </Grid>    
</Window>
```

How should I be binding that `ContentControl` such that the Window's ViewModel will be passed through to its `DataTemplateSelector`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"              
                    ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" />
```

Edit:

I agree with Aaron though, that this might not be the best way to accomplish things. You said you're using a ViewModel. The easiest way would probably be to bind your ItemsControl to a new "SelectedCollection" property on your Viewmodel that exposes the wanted collection. Then in your flag (assuming it is a property) you can fire propertychanged for "SelectedCollection".

Comment: I believe referring to the `DataContext` property explicitly + using RelativeSource is what I was missing, thank you. I have since abandoned the DataTemplateSelector approach, as you guys have mentioned; DTC appears to be meant for applying different templates to members of a *collection* of objects. I've found success using a `DataTrigger` to swap DataTemplates instead.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of things going on here...

You said you are using the `DataTemplateSelector` to either display collection A or collection B, while at the same time you stated you are setting one of the collections as the `DataContext` of the Window.

If you want to hide the data in one collection perform filtering on the collection itself. Another approach is to run the binding through an `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter`. Yet another solution could be to have two UI elements bound to each collection respectively and change the `Visiblity` of the UI element based on the value in your ViewModel.

Lot's of different options...and if I understand you correctly the `DataTemplateSelector` should not be one of them.

Comment: Apologies if this wasn't clear: I am not setting *one* of the collections as the DataContext, I'm setting the ViewModel which contains *both* collections as the DataContext. Nonetheless, having looked into this further, I agree that a DataTemplateSelector is *not* the correct solution!